# Problema de posicionamiento con leaftlet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

Tengo un problema al visualizar un mapa con leaftlet, el mapa se muestra como pequeños fragmentos que no están unidos de acuerdo a un mapa convencional, he agregado los estilos pero al agregarlos el mapa desaparece completamente, ademas se debería mostrar solo en un cuadrado de 500 px, pero al hacer scroll se desborda a toda la pagina.

Se que es problema de estilos, ¿como podría solucionarlo?

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

```css
#map{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas cargando solamente los **.js**, te faltaba cargar los **.css** de la librería. Es importante tener MUY claras las dependencia y el leer bien la documentación antes de importar cualquier tipo de librería.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

```css
#map{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

**Referencia:** [Documentación](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)